# Why does the spacing in math mode change when the text of a tikz node is centered?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, spacing

Given two nodes with same content, for example `$a = 1$`, the spacing is different depending on the text alignment of the respective node, i.e. when the text is centered, the spacing is greater. The problem seems to occur just in case of using inline math mode within a tikz node.

An example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[text box/.style={draw, text width=5cm}]
\node[text box, align=center] at (0, 2) {$a = 1$};
\node[text box, align=left] at (0, 0) {$a = 1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why is the spacing different?

One can prevent the different spacing by using `\mbox{$a = 1$}`. Is the a better way to get the same spacing for both alignments?

Comment: `align=center` installs the `text centered` key. Try `\node[text box, text badly centered] ...` instead.

Comment: @MarkWibrow That works. Thanks. What does it do? It seems not to be mentioned in the tikz manual.

Comment: @i8r The TikZ manual describes `align=flush left`, `align=flush center` and `align=flush right`.

Comment: see the pgfmanual page 225

Comment: The use of `text badly centered` or `align=flush center` fixes the particular problem of spacing in math mode. However `align=center` does produce typographically better results regarding the rest of the text, at least in my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to make the spaces in a formula unstretchable and unshrinkable, you just enclose the formula in braces.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[text box/.style={draw, text width=5cm}]
\node[text box, align=center] at (0, 2) {${a = 1}$};
\node[text box, align=left] at (0, 0) {$a = 1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can't have `align=center` and avoid a formula being stretched if, at TeX's eyes, the need arises. The difference between `text centered` and `text badly centered` is that in the first case finite glue is assigned to `\leftskip` and `\rightskip`, which decreases the raggedness at the expense of stretching spaces.

However, if the formula is in braces, it cannot participate to stretching.

Alternatively, use `align=flush center`, which sets the centering glue to first order infinite filling glue:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[text box/.style={draw, text width=5cm}]
\node[text box, align=flush center] at (0, 2) {$a = 1$};
\node[text box, align=left] at (0, 0) {$a = 1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

---

If you change your example into

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{badness warnings for centered text}

\begin{tikzpicture}[text box/.style={draw, text width=5cm}]
\node[text box, align=center] at (0, 2) {$a = 1$};
\node[text box, align=left] at (0, 0) {$a = 1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

you'll see in the log file the following warning:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 1762) in paragraph at lines 8--8
 [][][][]$\OML/cmm/m/it/10 a \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 = 1$
```

What happens is that TeX has been ordered to fill a box 5cm wide. Since `align=center` is in force, the available stretch comes from `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` which are set to 0pt plus 2em and from the stretchable glue resulting from `\thickmuskip` around the equals sign.

The characters globally occupy 18.0637pt; one em is, in this context, 10pt; the value of `\thickmuskip` is `5mu plus 5mu`, which results in a stretch of 2.77771pt. Five centimeters equal 142.26378pt.

Now, the space to be filled is, in points,

```
142.26378 - 18.0637 - 2*2.77771 = 118.64466
```

and we have available `2*(20+2.77771) = 45.55542`, so the available glue must overstretch by about 1.6 times its value. This means you get 7pt space at each side of the equals sign.

Conclusion: use `align=center` only if you're confident that the text will almost fill up the lines. Otherwise, use `align=flush center`.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, not only `align=center` but also `align=right` changes the spacing. For the later Ti*k*Z sets `\leftskip=0pt plus2em`; for the former it sets both `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` to the same value, `0pt plus2em`.

If you are familiar with TeX glue, you will recognize that the spaces between `a`, `=`, and `b` are generated by **stretchable glue**. The right `a=b` is even wider because the stretchability is less by `2em`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[text box/.style={draw, text width=5cm}]
        \path(0,-1)node[text box,align=left  ]{$a=b$}
             (0,-2)node[text box,align=center]{$a=b$}
             (0,-3)node[text box,align=right ]{$a=b$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

The remaining problem is why `align=left` is not a reflection of `align=right`.This is because `\parfillskip` contains `1.0fil` by default. Setting it to zero *solves* this problem.

[image]

```
\makeatletter
\tikzoption{text ragged}[]%
{\def\tikz@text@action{\parfillskip0pt\pgfutil@raggedright\rightskip0pt plus2em \spaceskip.3333em \xspaceskip.5em\relax}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[text box/.style={draw, text width=5cm}]
        \path(0,-1)node[text box,align=left  ]{$a=b$}
             (0,-2)node[text box,align=center]{$a=b$}
             (0,-3)node[text box,align=right ]{$a=b$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```